# How to center a button in material ui?

Tags: material-ui

Given below is the code which I coded using material ui.I'm still new to that area.I need to center my button.But it comes to the corner.Is there any problem in my code?

````
                <Button className={clsx(classes.button)} 
                type="submit"
                alignItems="center"
                variant="contained">
                 {'Sign Up'}
                </Button>
                </div>```



button:{
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    borderRadius: 8,
    border: 0,
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    width: "30%",
    padding: '10px 30px',
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }

alignItems="center" does not work for me.
````

Comment: The `align-items` property sets the `align-self` value on all direct children. In other words, if you have a flexbox container around your button, this is where the property needs to be applied. This is not MUI-specific behavior. Btw, you can remove `clsx` if you only apply one class.

Answer (score 0):

paper: {

```
textAlign: 'center',
color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
```

},

I enabled textAlign: 'center' and It fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
 justifyContent: 'center'
```

You can use justifyContent or AlignItems in

> display:flex

mode. Otherwise you can use `text-align: center` or `margin: auto` to make your child element center.